# Solar AC Disconnect - Fused or UnFused?

Tags: circuit-breaker, solar-panels

I'm installing a solar panel system with microinverters on each panel.  An AC disconnect must be installed outside.

I've learned that AC disconnects can be fused or unfused. - the unfused variety basically being a large power switch.  I will have a breaker in my panel for the AC circuit feed, so I'm wondering if there is any reason to have a fused AC disconnect. Seems to me that the breaker should meet the requirement to protect the circuit from overcurrent.

Does an AC disconnect for a solar power system have to include a fuse/breaker, or can I rely on the panel breaker to meet that requirement?

Comment: It depends on your AHJ, I don’t have to have fuses but do need a rapid shutdown system.

Comment: @EdBeal the upside of microinverters, if they're UL 1741 compliant, is they will shut off if grid is not present, which makes them compliant with Rapid Shutdown as easily as a disconnect.  Downside of microinverters is they're totally useless in a blackout.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica that downside has resolutions, like Enphase Empower which is a "hub" that will maintain power with your battery when the grid is down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You don't need a fuse here

The solar disconnect is only needed so the utility can shut down your solar system if it goes awry without having to fumble around in your breaker box or incur the risks of pulling your meter "hot".  As a result, a non-fused disconnect is A-OK here, as the breaker in the panel + the inherent limits of the solar source will protect the wiring from short-circuit or overcurrent.

Comment: ok, what about a scenario where the solar feed is line tapped and not backfed into a breaker in the main panel?

Comment: @dapug -- in a line-side tap, you need a full-blown service disconnecting setup with overcurrent protection.  I'd recommend strongly *against* line-side tapping though unless you are using hardware designed for that express purpose (hack-job line-side taps can really make a mess of service equipment, not to mention having to call UL out to field evaluate the mods....)